# Cost of S3 bucket for a month?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, web, cloud, web-frontend

I want to know , if I have a react frontend application (a simple portfolio) and I am hosting it on aws S3 bucket then how much charge will it cost me at the end of month.

Or can anyone suggest the best method to do this so I can reduce cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cost of hosting a React frontend application on AWS S3 bucket can vary depending on the amount of data you transfer and the number of HTTPs requests you make. For a year, **you can transfer 50 GB of data and serve 2 million requests a month, for free.** After that, **it will cost you 8-2 cents per GB**, depending on how much data you transfer, plus 1 cent per 10,000 HTTPs requests.

**You will also have to pay for your custom domain.** However, you will get a free public SSL certificate from AWS Certificate Manager.

Remember, these are just estimates and the actual cost can vary. It’s always a good idea to check the ***AWS Cloudfront pricing page*** for the most up-to-date information.

As for reducing cost, you might want to consider using AWS’ free tier if your usage is within its limits. Also, optimizing your application to make fewer requests and transfer less data can help reduce costs.